# Methord to convert json data to byte format and back

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google pub/sub to move data from one module to another , pub/sub needs to data to be encoded into bytes thus my code looks like this

module1

```
       data = json.dumps(tick[0])
       message_id = topic.publish(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

module2

```
      json_raw = message.data.decode('utf-8').replace("'",'"')
      jmsg = json.loads(json_raw)
```

here the json.loads raises an error that  "Expecting value: line 1 column 16 (char 15)" how do I fix this during conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base64` encode and prefix to mark it, just like below:

`for k, v in d.items():
    try:
        d[k] = base64.b64encode(v)
        d[k] = 'base64_' + d[k]
    except:
        pass`

Then dump it.

You have to rewrite the client to load this json to the raw data.

Comment: I still have the same problem on the client side. there seems to be a problem in the decoded data as the json.loads cant convert it into a json. it says something is missing but the json structure seems to be fine

Comment: After encode in server, values are all str, so the content can be decoded by client.

Comment: And client send the message to the sever in the same way, encoding in client and decoding in server